# Flycheck warning in Emacs’ *Messages* buffer are not displayed correctly

Tags: emacs, message, flycheck

The following is an example of how my flycheck errors show up on emacs:

```
Method name &quot;createQATask&quot; doesn&#x27;t conform to 
&#x27;[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$&#x27; pattern [invalid-name]
```

Here are the checkers I’m running (checked through `C-c ! v`):

```
Syntax checkers for buffer __manifest__.py in python-mode:

First checker to run:

  python-flake8
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /usr/bin/python3
    - configuration file: Not found
    - `flake8' module:    Found at "/home/devdesk4/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/__init__.py"
    - next checkers:      python-pylint, python-mypy

Checkers that may run as part of the first checker's chain:

  python-pylint
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /usr/bin/python3
    - configuration file: Found at "/home/devdesk4/.pylintrc"
    - `pylint' module:    Found at "/home/devdesk4/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py"
    - next checkers:      python-mypy

Checkers that could run if selected:

  python-pycompile  select
    - may enable:    yes
    - executable:    Found at /usr/bin/python3
    - next checkers: python-mypy
```

I’ve tried disabling `python-pylint`’s configuration file, but the behavior still remains. I’ve also tried a minimal `.emacs` configuration which only contained the following:

```
(setq package-archives                                                                                                                                                        
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")                                                                                                                             
        ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")                                                                                                                 
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")                                                                                                                      
        ("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))

(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init
  (global-flycheck-mode t))
```

Are those symbols (`&quot;`, `&#x27;`) not being displayed properly, or is this some sort of default flycheck configuration that I can override?

**April 25, 2020 Update (Possible Solution)**

Weirdly, I executed `pip install --upgrade pylint` just to check if I really had the latest version of `pylint`, and it upgraded from `2.3.0` to `2.4.4`, and that fixed the issue.

However, this solution conflicts with using https://pypi.org/project/pylint-odoo/, because it reverts me back to version `2.3.0` which has those html-escape sequences.

**Same-day update**

It’s [confirmed](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1746#issuecomment-619369897) to be an upstream bug in Pylint.

Comment: Since links can become unusable, it is best to include a summary of the link content here directly. The image can be uploaded to SO and inlined. In this case, it would be better to type the message in a code block. Code blocks are created by indenting with 4 spaces. See how I edited the question.

Comment: Is this something from your code or is it in Emacs itself? In other words, do you see this if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) and you then load Flycheck etc.? If so, then consider reporting it as a bug or feature request, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @HackerBoss I agree, that’s better! :)

@Drew How would I go about enabling `flycheck` inside an `emacs -Q` buffer? Nothing comes up when running `M-x` then typing `flycheck`.

Comment: `emacs -Q` starts with no user configuration.  It's a blank slate, and it's as close as possible to a common starting point.  You can execute whatever commands in e.g. the scratch buffer needed to reproduce the problem, and thus provide us with a minimal example.

Comment: @jpkotta Yeah, I noticed nothing’s enabled inside it. Although, how would I enable `flycheck` inside? It seems like my installation of `flycheck` isn’t being read while in this mode.

Comment: Probably do whatever your init.el does.  If you don't know how it works (e.g. you're using spacemacs or similar), add the directory flycheck is in to `load-path`, and `(require 'flycheck)`.

Answer (score 0):

> The following is an example of how my flycheck errors show up on emacs:
>
> `Method name &quot;createQATask&quot; doesn&#x27;t conform to &#x27;[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$&#x27; pattern [invalid-name]`

The linter evidentially believes it should be producing HTML output.

By the looks of it you are running all of `python-flake8`, `python-pylint`, and `python-mypy`.  I suggest that you firstly test them one at a time to establish which one is producing that output, and then look at the documentation for that tool to find out how to prevent it from generating HTML.

Comment: I disabled every checker except for `python-pylint` via `M-x flycheck-disable-checker`, and it seems like it’s the culprit. However, running `pylint` command manually on the file produces the following output: `wizards/create_qa.py:32:4: C0103: Method name "createQATask" doesn't conform to '[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$' pattern (invalid-name)`

which is how I would want `flycheck` to display the message inside an emacs buffer.

Comment: http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/1.6.0/run.html#command-line-options says: "`--output-format=<format>` Select output format (text, html, custom)."

Comment: I’m on PyLint version 2.3.0, and reading the changelogs for `pylint` makes it seem to me that the `html` `output-format` option has been deprecated. Testing this via setting `output-format` to `html` in my `~/.pylintrc` confirms this, since running `pylint` on a python file errors out: `pylint.exceptions.InvalidReporterError: html`. Setting it to `colorized` has the expected behavior, though (and displays the symbols mentioned in the question correctly), but still doesn’t display the symbols correctly when using pylint with flycheck.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the docs I looked at seemed like they were showing me the latest version.  Have you checked how flycheck is invoking pylint yet?